# Why use steps_per_epoch when replicating a tf.dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am learning tensorflow and going trough the example code here: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/tf-keras

Here is a short code snippet showing how the input to the model.fit function is made.

```
def input_fn(dataset,shuffle, n_epoch,s_batch):
    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.batch(s_batch)
    return dataset

n_epoch=10
s_batch=100
s_samples=number of samples in the training data

training_dataset_input=input_fn(
    training_dataset,
    shuffle=True,
    num_epochs=n_epoch,
    batch_size=s_batch)

mymodel.fit(training_dataset_input,epochs=n_epoch,steps_per_epoch=int(s_samples/s_batch)) </i>
```

My problem is understanding how an epoch works. I thought that one epoch is one complete runtrough of the whole dataset. But when setting the argument steps_per_epoch the training continue where it left on the same dataset, it does not seem to restart at the beginning.
So what is then the difference between:

`mymodel.fit(training_dataset_input,epochs=n_epoch,steps_per_epoch=int(s_samples/s_batch))`

and just exhausting the whole replicated dataset in one epoch

`mymodel.fit(training_dataset_input)`

Both of these fit methods will use the whole dataset 10 times, and do the same number of training steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when setting the argument steps_per_epoch the training continue where it left on the same dataset, it does not seem to restart at the beginning. So what is then the difference

If `steps_per_epoch` is not set then 1 epoch is 1 complete run through the data.

If `steps_per_epoch` is set then 1 "epoch" is the number of training steps this value is set to then (as you point out) the next "epoch" starts from where the last one left off.

This feature is useful if you want to do a validation run, etc more frequently on a huge dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much for the the answer. What you say makes sense. However I still don't understand why you would duplicate the data before running through the whole dataset once instead of just running through it for several epochs where1 epoch is a complete run through of the data.

Comment: My pleasure. If it helps you can always upvote/accept it. Bear in mind that you don't *actually* duplicate/copy it. `repeat()` is a cheap operation that just rereads it in a similar way to running through another true epoch. If I have a dataset of 250 batches and want 500 steps I could just do 2 traditional epochs but if i want a validation run every 100 steps then I could use the above to train on exactly the same number of batches but have an 'epoch' defined as 100 batches so that I get visibility of the validation stats more frequently

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer, I did understand how to do it right the first time